# How to Programmatically create a sitemap in Asp.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitemap

I am trying to create a sitemap for a site that almost daily has pages being added and removed. My understanding is that there is a way to programmatically create a sitemap to stay up to date with these changes, but over the last few days I haven't been able to find any documentation within the last several years. I searched asp.net, and the latest article is in 2010.

If anyone has any insight, valid links, or recommendations I'd very much appreciate it!

Comment: Is it a page generated by a CMS or it will actually add a new Action / View?

Comment: If you are hosting in IIS there is a sitemap feature available if you have enabled the seo tools.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I had to talk to someone to try to figure out the answer to your question, we are using some sort of custom CMS like system that is basically resulting in new pages which don't ever show up in our project on Visual Studio

Comment: @RossBush we are using IIS, I will look more into the seo tools for that, thanks!